# Prove that $m(\{x\in[0,1]:\lim \sup_{j\rightarrow\infty}f_j(x)\geq\frac{1}{2}\})\geq\frac{1}{2}$ under these conditions...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

**Question:** Suppose for each $j\in\mathbb{N}, f_j:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable such that $0\leq f_j\leq\frac{3}{2}$ and $\int_0^1 f_j dm=1$.  Prove that $m(\{x\in[0,1]:\lim \sup_{j\rightarrow\infty}f_j(x)\geq\frac{1}{2}\})\geq\frac{1}{2}$.

**Thoughts/Attempt**: Let $A=\{x\in[0,1]:\lim \sup_{j\rightarrow\infty}f_j(x)\geq\frac{1}{2}\}$, and $B=\{x\in[0,1]:\lim \sup_{j\rightarrow\infty}f_j(x)<\frac{1}{2}\}$.  Suppose, by contradiction, that $m(A)<\frac{1}{2}$.  So, we can split up the integral as $$\int_0^1f_jdm=\int_Af_jdm+\int_Bf_jdm$$ where we get equality by the integral in the assumption.  Now, $\int_Af_jdm<\frac{1}{2}$, by our (contradiction) assumption.  And, $\int_Bf_jdm<\frac{1}{2}$, using our set $B$.  Therefore, $$\int_0^1f_jdm<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$$ a contradiction, since this integral must equal $1$ from our assumption.  Hence, we contradict that $m(A)<\frac{1}{2}$.

However, I am not quite sure if this works, because our sets are dealing with the $\lim\sup f_j(x)$ as $x\in[0,1]$, but wouldn't I have to compensate in the integral since the image of $f_j$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I found a simple solution based in properties of $\limsup_nf_n$. I hope this is clear enough. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the $\limsup$ for your integrals over $B$, I suggest using Fatou's lemma.

Fatou's lemma only applies to non-negative functions, and $\tfrac 3 2 - f_n(x)$ is a non-negative function. Applying Fatou to $\tfrac 3 2 - f_n(x)$ on $B$, we have
$$ \int_B \liminf_{n \to \infty}\left(\tfrac 3 2 - f_n (x)\right) dm \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_B \left(\tfrac 3 2 - f_n (x)\right) dm,$$
or equivalently,
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_B f_n(x) dm \leq \int_B \limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \leq \tfrac 1 2 m(B).$$

Meanwhile, the correct inequality for the integrals over $A$ is
$$ \int_A f_n(x) dm \leq \tfrac 3 2 m(A)$$
for each $n \in \mathbb N$. (It seems like you've missed the factor of $\tfrac 3 2$, coming from the upper bound on $f_n$.)

Thus
$$ 1 = \limsup_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx \leq \tfrac 3 2 m(A) + \tfrac 1 2 m(B) =  m(A) + \tfrac 1 2,$$
which clearly implies that $m(A) \geq \tfrac 1 2$.

Comment: just a quick question regarding the bounds... for the integral over $A$, it is $\leq\frac{3}{2}m(A)$, and for the integral over $B$, it is $\leq\frac{1}{2}m(B)$.  Could you go over how you got that inequality?  I know it comes from the bounds and Markov/Chebyshev, but I suppose I am not seeing it immediately.

Comment: It's simply that if $f\leq c$ for some constant $c$, then $ \int_A f \leq \int_A c = c\mu(A)$.

Comment: ah, so it is just using linearity of the integral.  I just posted a new question on MSE about different variations on the assumptions.  I suppose I am just having a bit of confusion going from integral to measure.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\begin{align}
 1=\int f_n &=\int_{\{f_n\geq\frac12\}}f_n+\int_{\{f_n<\frac12\}}f_n\leq \frac32\lambda\Big(f_n\geq\frac12\Big) + \frac12\lambda\Big(f_n<\frac12\Big)\\
&=\lambda\Big(f_n\geq\frac12\Big)+\frac12
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$\lambda\Big(f_n\geq\frac12\Big)\geq\frac12\qquad\text{for all}\quad n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Notice that
$$\begin{align}
\Big\{\limsup_jf_j\geq\frac12\Big\}\supset\limsup_j\Big\{f_j\geq\frac12\Big\}=\bigcap_n\bigcup_{m\geq n}\Big\{f_m\geq\frac12\Big\}\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}$$

Putting things together we obtain
$$\lambda\Big(\limsup_jf_j\geq\frac12\Big)\geq\lim_n\lambda\Big(\bigcup_{m\geq n}\{f_m\geq\frac12\}\Big)\geq\limsup_n\lambda\Big(f_n\geq\frac12\Big)\geq\frac12$$

---

Comment:

The set inequality $\eqref{one}$ is clear since $x\in\bigcap_n\bigcup_{m\geq n}\Big\{f_n\geq\frac12\Big\}$ implies that $f_n(x)\geq\frac12$ infinitely many times, and so $\limsup_nf_n(x)\geq\frac12$.

Comment: Very nice!  After Kenny's most recent comment, the first line makes much more sense, and the rest follows pretty easily :)  Thank you, @OliverDiaz!!!

Comment: I really like this!