# A few questions regarding using Markov/Chebyshev and writing the Lebesgue measure in terms of the Lebesgue Integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I just asked a question here [Prove that $m(\{x\in[0,1]:\lim \sup_{j\rightarrow\infty}f_j(x)\geq\frac{1}{2}\})\geq\frac{1}{2}$ under these conditions...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3769125/736765), and I am having a hard time seeing the bounds on the integral.  I know it is dealing with Markov/Chebyshev, but I am just not completely seeing it.  So, I wanted to ask the following:

1. In the question above, how exactly are the bounds determined?  In particular, how do the sets $A$ and $B$ determine the bounds of the integral by generating the factor in front of $m(A)$ and $m(B)$, respectively?  I assume it is just Markov, but it appears as the bounds on $f_j(x)$ is also playing a role I am not clearly seeing.
2. Suppose, for instance, $0\leq f_j(x)\leq 1$ instead of the bounds in the original problem... how would the value (bounds in terms of the measure, I suppose I should say) of the integral change?
3. In the sets $A$ and $B$, what if $\lim\inf$ was used instead of $\lim\sup$?  Would that matter, or would that only make using Fatou for $B$ a bit easier since we wouldn't have to come up with equivalent statements for $\lim\sup$.
4. In the problem, $x\in[0,1]$, but,$f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  If instead of $\mathbb{R}$ we had some other interval, say $[0,1]$ (that is, say $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$), how would that have affected the integral bounds in terms of the measure?

I suppose with these questions I am just trying to get a better sense of what I'm looking for and playing with when it comes to dealing with measurability problems.  I would really appreciate any insight you all have!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1.** If $f \leq g$ on a set $A$, then $\int_A f \ dm \leq \int_A g \ dm$. Furthermore, if $g = c$, where $c$ is a constant, then $\int_A g = c \ m(A)$. Thus, if $f \leq c$ on $A$, with $c$ constant, then $\int_A f \ dm \leq c \ m(A)$. That's all there is to it.

In the question that you linked, $f_n \leq \tfrac 3 2 $ for all $n$ everywhere (and in particular in $A$), so $\int_A f_n \ dm \leq \tfrac 3 2 m(A)$. Furthermore, $\limsup_{n \to \infty} f_n \leq \tfrac 1 2 $ on $B$, since $B$ is *by definition* the set of points where $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \leq \tfrac 1 2$, so $\int_B \limsup_{n \to \infty}f_n \ dm \leq \tfrac 1 2 m(B)$.

We're not using Markov or Chebyshev. (That said, Markov and Chebyshev are proved using very similar ideas...)

**Question 2.** If $0 \leq f_n (x) \leq 1$, then we have $\int_A f_n \leq 1 . m(A)$, so
$$ 1 = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n \ dm \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_A f_n \ dm + \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_B f_n \ dm \leq m(A) + \tfrac 1 2 m(B) = \tfrac 1 2 m(A) + \tfrac 1 2 $$
Then $m(A) \geq 1$. But $A \subset [0, 1]$. So $m(A) = 1$.

**Question 3.** If we change $\limsup$ to $\liminf$ in the question but change nothing else, then the proof wouldn't work. For if $B := \{ x \in [0, 1] : \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \leq \tfrac 1 2 \}$, then we get
$$ \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_B f_n \ dm \geq \int_B \liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n \ dm \leq \tfrac 1 2 m(B).$$
The $\geq $ inequality messes up the proof.

**Question 4**. In some sense, the $f_n$'s in the original problem can already be thought of as functions with bounded images. Since $0 \leq f_n \leq \tfrac 3 2$ by assumption, you can think of the $f_n$'s as functions $[0, 1] \to [0, \tfrac 3 2]$. Making the $f_n$'s functions to $[0, 1]$ is like saying that $0 \leq f_n \leq 1$ for all $x$. We've dealt with this scenario in Question 2.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Just out of curiosity, if we'd flip the inequality in the set and use $\lim\inf$ then could we use this?

Comment: We could flip the entire question around. For example, define $g_n = \tfrac 3 2 - f_n$, and pose the question in terms of $g_n$. Then would have lim infs instead of lim sups, and the proof would work.

Comment: Very neat.  I really appreciate all your help with this problem, and the other one!  Thank you!

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind:  For your answer to question $2$, in your equation line, you are essentially saying that $m(A)=-m(B)$.... why?
I suppose that, along with in the question I tagged you have $\frac{3}{2}m(A)+\frac{1}{2}m(B)=m(A)+\frac{1}{2}$ is just confusing me...

Comment: @User7238 I'm saying that $m(A) = 1-m(B)$. This is because $m(A) + m(B) = m(A \cup B) = m([0, 1]) = 1$.

Comment: Ah, okay, and that is because $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, right?  If, for instance, $f:[0,2]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, then $m(A)=2-m(B)$, correct?

Comment: @User7238  No. The Lebesgue measure of an interval is always the length of the interval. So $m([a, b]) = b- a$.

Comment: okay, but then where is the $1$ coming from in "$m(A)=1-m(B)$"?  Is that because in question 2, I asked what would happen if $0\leq f_n(X)\leq 1$?  So, in the original question, since $0\leq f_n(x)\leq\frac{3}{2}$, we would have $m(A)=\frac{3}{2}-m(B)$?

Comment: No. The $1$ comes from the fact that $m(A) + m(B) = m(A \cup B) = m([0, 1]) = 1 - 0 = 1$. In other words, $1$ is the length of the interval $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Right, so if instead of $[0,1]$, we were working with $[0,2]$, that is, $f:[0,2]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, why wouldn't we have $m(A)+m(B)=m([0,2])\implies m(A)=2-m(B)$?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread your comment! Yes, if we were working with $[0, 2]$, then we would have $m(A) = 2 - m(B)$.

Comment: Ah, okay, very good :)  I was definitely getting a little worried there; I thought I was missing something super obvious.  As always, thank you so much for all your help!!